# In service fabric do you need to call CommitAsync when just reading a value?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

When using a reliable dictionary in service fabric, you have to access everything within a transaction. However when reading you are not changing anything, so it doesn't seem to make any sense to call CommitAsync.

Are there any downsides of not calling CommitAsync?

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no downsides. Just try to free your transaction as fast as possible.

By the way, I have noticed that sometimes somehow values that are returned from reliable collection could be modified. It was a list in my case, so I was unable to enumerate it properly. Pretty sure there were no my code that could modify that value. So my suggestion is to make a copy of a value if it is a reference type and work with that copy, freeing transaction, even if you are not going to modify the value.

Comment: Focussing a bit on the comment - that indicates to me that the framework is changing the list. Is this something you can confirm? Or could it be that your code is changing it from another method?

Comment: @NickRandell I cannot be 100% sure that there were no my code that was changing the value, however since I started make copies, this problem has gone. You can try and reproduce the issue: just simulate several hundreds of concurrent calls that modify this collection on a single row. I cannot say for sure that SF could modify something by itself.

Comment: @NickRandell I just realized that when you call `GetOrAddAsync` you probably will create something and at the moment you will not have a transaction object. Will something be saved if we will not create a transaction? If yes, then ok, but if no, then you have to create it and call `CommitAsync` even if you just want to read something and check existence.